# How to click on "Submit" button from a website

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I'm new to VBA and have stumbled upon this one problem where I coultnt use vba code to automatically click on a "Submit" button from a website. I have tweaked my code many times but it always skipped the line "e.click". Below is my recent code and an image of the website's elements.

Hope someone can shed some lights here.

```vb
Set tags = objIE.Document.getElementById("alltab").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each e In tags
    If e.getAttribute("alt") = "Submit a Contract" Then
        e.Click
    End If
next
```

[website's elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gNPo.png)

Comment: I set a break point just before the problem and slowly step through using the immediate window to find out if e is set to the correctly, if I should consider getting e by class or ID, Is e enabled and ready at the time i click, is the page still loading, is my click intercepted by an invisible layer, am I allowing sufficient time for a page response after each click, do I have to click e or can I send a Space or Enter, are there any other properties of e that I can use to work around the problem?  Each answer brings me a step closer until I zero in on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector for the `alt` attribute. Nice and fast. You don't want to loop an entire collection if you don't have to. Also, in any loop you would want to `Exit For` after found I believe.

```
objIE.document.querySelector("[alt='Submit a Contract']").click
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr. I tried your code but it gave me an "Object Required" error. Not really sure why. (PS: I forgot to put Next the loop in the post, thanks for catching it ).

Comment: 1. Step through with F8 line by line to see if it is a timing issue. Ensure page has loaded before executing above line. 2. If error remains check whether your element is inside a parent iframe or frame tag. Let me know,

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code, from your screenshot it seems that the hyperlink (html a tag) not inside the alltab table.

[image]

Please try to find the table by the class name and modify your code to add an ID property:

Find the table by ID property (add an ID property for the second table):

```
Set tags = doc.getElementById("table id").getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each e In tags
    If e.getAttribute("alt") = "Submit a Contract" Then
        e.Click
    End If
Next e
```

or

Find the table by class name:

```
Set tags = doc.getElementsByClassName("belowDealButtonBox")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each e In tags
    If e.getAttribute("alt") = "Submit a Contract" Then
        e.Click
    End If
Next e
```